# How do I keep buttons inside a div when scaling?

Tags: html, css, button, responsive

Want to keep the same button layout when scaling the window or in mobile view. For some reason the buttons won't stay inside the div and get rearranged after the width of about 1160px.

And also the letters don't scale proportionally and are not centered inside the buttons anymore even though I used vw.

Hope someone can help me out, thanks!

```js
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100 % ;
}#
keyboard {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40 vw;
  right: 6 vw;
  top: 7 vw;

}#
zero {
  position: relative;
  left: 4.8 vw;
}

.btn {
  border - radius: 1.5 vw;
  font - size: 3 vw;
  width: 4.5 vw;
  background - color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
  border - color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border - width: 0.5 vw;
  color: rgb(255, 208, 0);
  text - align: center;
  font - family: "Microgramma";
  text - shadow: 0 0 0.5 vw# ff7b00;
  margin: 0.1 vw;
  margin - top: 0.2 vw;
  margin - bottom: 0.2 vw;


}
.btn2 {
  border - radius: 1.5 vw;
  font - size: 2 vw;
  min - width: 10 vw;
  background - color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
  border - color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border - width: 0.5 vw;
  color: rgb(255, 208, 0);
  font - family: "Microgramma";
  text - shadow: 0 0 0.5 vw# ff7b00;
  margin: 0.1 vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 3 vw;

}
```

```html
<div id="keyboard">
  <div id="firstLine">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="O" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">O</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="N" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">N</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="G" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">G</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="R" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">R</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="B" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="7" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="8" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="9" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">9</button>
  </div>
  <div id="secondLine">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="X" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">X</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="Z" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">Z</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="U" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">U</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="W" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">W</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="C" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="4" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="5" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="6" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">6</button>
  </div>
  <div id="thirdLine">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="I" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">I</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="K" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">K</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="E" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">E</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="F" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">F</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="Y" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">Y</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="1" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="2" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="3" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">3</button>
  </div>
  <div id="fourthLine">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="M" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">M</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="S" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">S</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="T" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">T</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="L" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">L</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="J" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">J</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="zero" value="0" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">0</button>
  </div>
  <div id="fifthLine">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="P" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">P</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="Q" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">Q</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="D" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">D</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="A" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="V" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">V</button>
  </div>

  <div id="sixthLine">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="H" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">H</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn2" value=" " onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">SPACE</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn2" onclick="backspace();playbtnsound()">DELETE</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn2" onclick="clearit();playbtnsound()">CLEAR</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this property :

```
#firstLine ,
#secondLine ,
#thirdLine ,
#fourthLine ,
#fifthLine ,
#sixthLine {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

or use this property:

```
#firstLine ,
#secondLine ,
#thirdLine ,
#fourthLine ,
#fifthLine ,
#sixthLine {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) instead of `div`

```css
html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#keyboard {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40vw;
    right: 6vw;
    top: 7vw;

}


.btn {
    border-radius: 1.5vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
    width: 4.5vw;
    background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
    border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border-width: 0.5vw;
    color: rgb(255, 208, 0);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Microgramma";
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.5vw #ff7b00;
    margin: 0.1vw 0.2vw;
        
}
.max-btn {
    min-width: 10vw;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.btn-placeHolder{
   width: 4.5vw;
}
```

```html
<table id="keyboard">
  <tr id="firstLine">
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="O" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">O</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="N" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">N</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="G" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">G</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="R" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">R</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="B" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">B</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="7" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">7</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="8" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">8</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="9" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">9</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="secondLine" >
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="X" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">X</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="Z" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">Z</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="U" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">U</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="W" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">W</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="C" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">C</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="4" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">4</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="5" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">5</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="6" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">6</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="thirdLine" >
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="I" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">I</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="K" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">K</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="E" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">E</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="F" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">F</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="Y" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">Y</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="1" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">1</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="2" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">2</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="3" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">3</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="fourthLine" >
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="M" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">M</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="S" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">S</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="T" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">T</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="L" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">L</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="J" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">J</button></td>
    <td class="btn-placeHolder"></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" id="zero" value="0" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">0</button></td>
    <td class="btn-placeHolder"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="fifthLine" >
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="P" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">P</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="Q" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">Q</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="D" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">D</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="A" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">A</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn" value="V" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">V</button></td>
    <td class="btn-placeHolder"> </td>
    <td class="btn-placeHolder"> </td>
    <td class="btn-placeHolder"> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="sixthLine" >
    <td> <button type="button" class="btn" value="H" onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">H</button></td>
    <td class="btn-placeHolder"> </td>
    <td colspan="2"> <button type="button" class="btn max-btn" value=" " onclick="input_Run(this.value);playbtnsound()">SPACE</button></td>
    <td colspan="2"> <button type="button" class="btn max-btn" onclick="backspace();playbtnsound()">DELETE</button></td>
    <td colspan="2"> <button type="button" class="btn max-btn" onclick="clearit();playbtnsound()">CLEAR</button></td>
    </div>
</table>
```